# Mechanize is not loading full webpage after search submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mechanize

Why I am not getting the products on [this][1] page when searching a " " space in the search form I only get the menus but not the search result products

Ruby code:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'mysql2'
require 'logger'
require 'mechanize'
agent = Mechanize.new{|a| a.log = Logger.new(STDERR) }
agent.user_agent_alias = 'Windows Mozilla'
agent.read_timeout = 60
def add_cookie(agent, uri, cookie)
uri = URI.parse(uri)
Mechanize::Cookie.parse(uri, cookie) do |cookie|
agent.cookie_jar.add(uri, cookie)
end
end
login_page = agent.get "http://www.example.com.mx/login.php?location=%2F"
login_form = login_page.form_with(:method => 'POST')
email_field = login_form.field_with(name: "correo_ingresar") 
password_field = login_form.field_with(name: "password") 
email_field.value = 'user@example.com'
password_field.value = 'password'
home_page = login_form.submit
myarray = home_page.body.scan(/SetCookie\(\"(.+)\", \"(.+)\"\)/)
myarray.each{|line| add_cookie agent, 'http://www.example.com.mx', "#{line[0]}=#{line[1]}"}
add_cookie(agent, 'http://www.example.com.mx', "forzar_existencias=1; path=/; domain=www.example.com.mx")
add_cookie(agent, 'http://www.example.com.mx', "articulos_mostrar=50; path=/; domain=www.example.com.mx")
add_cookie(agent, 'http://www.example.com.mx', "forz_existencias=1=; path=/; domain=www.example.com.mx")
add_cookie(agent, 'http://www.example.com.mx', "no_actualiza=1; path=/; domain=www.example.com.mx")
add_cookie(agent, 'http://www.example.com.mx', "orden_mostrar=8; path=/; domain=www.example.com.mx")
add_cookie(agent, 'http://www.example.com.mx', "page=1; path=/; domain=www.example.com.mx")
add_cookie(agent, 'http://www.example.com.mx', "precio_inicio=0; path=/; domain=www.example.com.mx")
add_cookie(agent, 'http://www.example.com.mx', "location=%2Farticulos.php%3Fbuscar%3D%2B; path=/; domain=www.example.com.mx")

search_form = home_page.forms.first
search_field = search_form.field_with(name: "buscar") 
search_field.value = ' '
search_results = search_form.submit
resultados = 'http://example.com.mx/articulos.php?buscar=+'
```

I downloaded the Live HTTP Headers addon for firefox with firebug. when I fill with a space and click on the search button on the [webpage][1] I get the following results on live HTTP headers.

```
http://example.com.mx/articulos.php?buscar=+

GET /articulos.php?buscar=+ HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com.mx
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://example.com.mx/articulos.php?buscar=+
Cookie: _ga=GA1.3.162897808.1438611502; _gat=1
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 08 Aug 2015 04:29:40 GMT
Server: Apache
x-powered-by: PHP/5.4.30
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html
----------------------------------------------------------
http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&_v=j37&a=1988602157&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com.mx%2Farticulos.php%3Fbuscar%3D%2B&ul=en-us&de=UTF-8&dt=Sistemas%20Aplicados&sd=24-bit&sr=1920x1080&vp=1903x969&je=0&_u=AACAAEABI~&jid=&cid=162897808.1438611502&tid=UA-58813310-1&z=90642832

GET /collect?v=1&_v=j37&a=1988602157&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com.mx%2Farticulos.php%3Fbuscar%3D%2B&ul=en-us&de=UTF-8&dt=Sistemas%20Aplicados&sd=24-bit&sr=1920x1080&vp=1903x969&je=0&_u=AACAAEABI~&jid=&cid=162897808.1438611502&tid=UA-58813310-1&z=90642832 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google-analytics.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0
Accept: image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://example.com.mx/articulos.php?buscar=+
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Mon, 07 Aug 1995 23:30:00 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Last-Modified: Sun, 17 May 1998 03:00:00 GMT
x-content-type-options: nosniff
Content-Type: image/gif
Date: Wed, 29 Jul 2015 12:33:33 GMT
Server: Golfe2
Content-Length: 35
Age: 834969
Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic,p=0
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-cache=Set-Cookie, proxy-revalidate
----------------------------------------------------------
http://example.com.mx/resultados.php

POST /resultados.php HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com.mx
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://example.com.mx/articulos.php?buscar=+
Content-Length: 204
Cookie: _ga=GA1.3.162897808.1438611502; _gat=1
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
opcion=&buscar=+&page=1&articulos_mostrar=10&orden_mostrar=1&seccion=&linea=&sublinea=&forz_existencias=1&precio_inicio=0&precio_final=20000&location=%252Farticulos.php%253Fbuscar%253D%252B&no_actualiza=1
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 08 Aug 2015 04:29:42 GMT
Server: Apache
x-powered-by: PHP/5.4.30
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Question is: how do I get the full products to show on the webpage so I can start scraping if it has a referer link and it does not automatically gets the products. [This][2] is the resulting HTML:

Comment: On a higher level: What are you actually interested in? Product prices? Automatically order stuff?

Comment: I am interested in getting all products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give 2 solutions, but only one uses a POST as you requested in your question:

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
agent.get("http://www.sistemasaplicados.com.mx/")
agent.page.forms.first.field_with(name: "buscar").value = ' '
result_page = agent.page.forms.first.submit
```

The other option is to encode your search term and use it in a simple the GET request (encoded in the URL) directly with nokogiri. In your particular case a search for "160GB" leads to following URL `http://www.sistemasaplicados.com.mx/articulos.php?buscar=160GB`, which you can just `GET`.

Btw, you do not necessarily need mechanize for all that, except you want to place orders into your account automatically or something like that. I assume you do that in the interest of sistemasaplicados otherwise I would consider this rude and it would bring you bad karma.

**Update**
When manually checking what is happening you should look what happens if JavaScript is disabled (in this case, there are no results). Then, with the "inspector", "console" or "developer tools" of your Browser (often opened by pressing F12) find out what happens. In your case a POST request to resultados.php is done. I found out with firefox, dev tools, "Network" tab. There also you find the relevant parameters to fire up in your POST request.

Comment: Hello Felix I did contact this webmaster, and no problem was seen with doing this. the purpose is to update my ecommerce with their inventory products

Comment: I already search, but when I get the output it only displays the Menu and the filters meno on the left of the page. How do I get the products to appear